# faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server

Tags: webservice-client

I am newbie to Web Services.
When I am trying to connect to a web service that shows

```
faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server
faultSubcode: 
faultString: Fault
faultActor: 
faultNode: 
faultDetail: 
{}cause:UnrecoverableClientError
{}code:SchemaError
{}desc:validation failure for ProcessShipmentRequest Error:UndeclaredPrefix:                Cannot resolve 'xsd:positiveInteger' as a QName: the prefix 'xsd' is not declared.
```

Can anybody please tell how to resolve this problem?